# How to select columns from string/list entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Could you please assist? I am trying to pass only specific columns into my select statement in entity framework,the columns are chosen depending on if a checkbox is checked for a particular column name. So if a user check the checkbox for product name then only the column `productName` will be passed to the select. this is so i can generate report based on columns selected, please note the code already works but generates for all columns and not specific ones.

please check my code below.

```
public FileContentResult GenerateExportForecastReport(bool productId,
          bool productName,
          bool productPrice,
          bool QTY,                                                        
         ) //returns true/false successfully                                                    
{
    try
    {
        var columns = new List<string>();
        var myproducts = ctx.Products.Where(a => a.productid == 6)

        if (productId==true)
            columns.Add(nameof(Products.productId));
        if (productName==true)
             columns.Add(nameof(Products.productName));
        if (productPrice==true)
            ​columns.Add(nameof(Products.productPrice));
         if (QTY==true)
            ​columns.Add(nameof(Products.QTY));

       joining columns
       var select = $"{string.Join(", ", columns)}";

      //this does not give any errors but passes one column which is a whole string and 
      does not seperate columns in my string
       var prdcts = myproducts.Select(a=> new {select}).ToList();

      //also tried but gives an error
      var prdcts = myproducts.Select(select).ToList();

...
```

Comment: imho, it is easier to populate one result model and then return only the columns selected by the user. `Select(a=> new {select})` - select is a string,  not a props list as you want

Comment: @benuto,i'm not sure i'm following what you are saying,could you please demo with a short snippet/code

Comment: You have to use https://dynamic-linq.net

Comment: 'read more' links are broken :(